# querying email in firebase in a public section (react native, js) returning null

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement a email search function with the backend being firebase's datastore.

Datastore:
[image]

Security rules

```
{
  "rules": {
        "users": {
      "$uid":{
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid ",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "public": {
        ".read": "auth != null", 
        "$uid":{
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".indexOn": ["userEmail"],
        }
      }
  }
}
```

For this instance, I'm trying to search for other users via their email in the public section of the data store.

```
export const searchEmail = ({ searchText }) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        firebase.database().ref()
        .child('public/uid/profile')
        .orderByChild('userEmail')
        .equalTo(searchText)
      //  .startAt(`${searchText}`)
      //  .endAt(`${searchText}`)
        .once('value', snapshot => {
          dispatch({ type: SEARCH_EMAIL_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
          const foundUser = snapshot.val();
          console.log('the found users are', foundUser);
          //the snap.val() is the returned data that's returned
          });
      };
};
```

I'm thinking its returning null because I have not referenced the UID properly in pathway but I havn't been able to figure out how to reference other user's UID other than the one currently logged in.

The alternative would be to create the public section that's completely public with .write rules that reflect. This way the UID won't be in the way..

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: HERE'S what the console log looks like:

```
search text changing!
searching firebase now!
'searching txt is ', 'T@t.com'
 FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "userEmail" at /public/uid/profile to your security rules for better performance 
   { type: 'search_email_success', payload: null }
   'the found users are', null
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a return:

```
export const searchEmail = ({ searchText }) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return firebase.database().ref()
            ...
```

Comment: Thanks Frank for the quick response. Although even though I add 'return' its still null.

Comment: Yeah, in hindsight I'm not really sure what the code is supposed to do. You return from the top-level, but also consume the snapshot in `once()`'s callback and send it off to `dispatch()`. It's indeed more likely that your path `'public/uid/profile'` is incorrect, as you probably want to use the `uid` **value** for the current user: `'public/'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid+'/profile'`.

Comment: Thanks Frank! Sorry I wasn't so clear. the dispatch is suppose to call a new action (SEARCH_EMAIL_SUCCESS) which triggers a new state for the page. currently i'm console logging the return to see if the mechanism works. If i use the currentUser.uid it only returns the currentUser's email, where as I'm trying to return the searched email in the data store. Does that make sense? I'm fairly new at this so I'm pretty sure I screwed up the path somewhere cuz I didn't know how to references the other users' uid in the 'pulic/uid/profile path of the datastore

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem. The way the datastore is setup, the userEmail is nested underneath profile and public so the path would be:

public/$uid/profile/userEmail.

I had a problem getting around the $uid aspect and after reviewing some documentation on reading and writing to the datastore I realized that the structure of the datastore was causing the search function not to work since. So I changed the path in which the user data is stored by removing the 'profile' level thereby flattening the data more. See image below for comparison between Test1 and test2 & 3.

[image]

Now when I query with orderByChild and search with T2@t.com, it works.

here's the code:

```
 console.log('searchEmail called and the text is', searchText);
  const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
  const oneRef = rootRef.child('public').orderByChild('userEmail');
        console.log('the order by user email is ', oneRef);
    oneRef.equalTo(`${searchText}`)
    .once('value', snapshot => {
      dispatch({ type: SEARCH_EMAIL_SUCCESS, payload: snapshot.val() });
      const foundUser = snapshot.val();
      console.log('the found user is', foundUser);
```

Now it returns the users who have been searched! Wooohoo!